# Logfile creation

Tags: python, logging

I have some loggings with a timestamp as name

```
logging_config.fileConfig( fname=ini_file, disable_existing_loggers=0 ) #, defaults, disable_existing_loggers)

logger = logging.getLogger("myLoggerABC")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Is it possible to configurate the logger that the logfile will be created with the first log-write-operation and not before.

Why?
When I have no reasons to log something, I will have many empty files. That's ugly.

Comment: As a workaround you can use a command to delete the empty files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `delay=True` in the handler's initialisation: see [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler), as long as you are using Python 2.6 or later (and if not, consider updating). This defers creating/opening a file until something is actually logged.